# Count the number of times a value exists in a list - KQL Kusto query

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

This is the end of my query, the relevant piece:

```
| project endpoint, clientName, siteName, duration, operation_Id, customDimensions, operation_ParentId, id, target, operation_Name, itemType, client_City, itemCount, type, name, data
| summarize NumberInGrouping = count(), operationIdSet = make_set(operation_Id), operationIdList = make_list(operation_Id) by endpoint, clientName, siteName
| mv-expand operationIdSet to typeof(string)
```

My question is, how do I do something similar to this:

```
| project endpoint, clientName, siteName, duration, operation_Id, customDimensions, operation_ParentId, id, target, operation_Name, itemType, client_City, itemCount, type, name, data
| summarize NumberInGrouping = count(), operationIdSet = make_set(operation_Id), operationIdList = make_list(operation_Id) by endpoint, clientName, siteName
| mv-expand operationIdSet to typeof(string)
| extend some_num = countif(array_contains(operationIdList, operationIdSet))
```

Notice the last line. This does not work because `countif` is not allowed in this context but I need something that can do the same thing. After mv-expand is ran, `operationIdSet` is a single value, not a list.

Therefore, my goal is to find out how many times the value in the `operationIdSet` column exists in the list in the `operationIdList` column but this must be done after mv-expand because only then is the data grouped correctly.

I tried this:

```
| mv-expand operationIdSet to typeof(string)
| summarize some_num = countif(set_has_element(operationIdList, tostring(operationIdSet))) by endpoint, clientName, siteName, NumberInGrouping, tostring(operationIdSet), tostring(operationIdList)
```

But `some_num` is always 1 so it's definitely not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `mv-apply` operator to iterate over the array and count the number of times a value exists in the list.

```
| project endpoint, clientName, siteName, duration, operation_Id, customDimensions, operation_ParentId, id, target, operation_Name, itemType, client_City, itemCount, type, name, data
| summarize NumberInGrouping = count(), operationIdSet = make_set(operation_Id), operationIdList = make_list(operation_Id) by endpoint, clientName, siteName
| mv-expand operationIdSet to typeof(string)
| mv-apply operationIdList on (
summarize some_num=countif(operationIdList == tostring(operationIdSet))
)
```

[FIDDLE](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/ContosoSales?query=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)

In the above code, the last line counts the number of times each `operation_Id` appears in the list of `operation_Id` values for each group using the mv-apply operator.